# Saleforce Admin Sharing Rule

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning

[Note: There is a Teacher Object with the fields such as Teacher Name, DateofJoining, and also a formula field called Experience]
My Task was to create a Public Group consisting of another user
and this user should only see teachers who have experience greater than 2 years
But when i create a sharing rule based on criteria the field name called Experience doesn't show up as it is a formula field.

So i got an idea of creating a new field(maybe a text or number data type) which would have the value of Experience in it. (But i have no idea on how to implement this)

Is there a way to implement this?
Any other solution is also well appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say.

Normal trick would be to create a helper field (text, number, whatever) and have piece of functionality that populates it. An "early flow" or "before insert, before update" trigger ideally. Worst case a normal flow, process builder or "after insert, after update" trigger. Something like "`if Experience__c != 'your formula here' then Experience__c = 'your formula here'`". Consult normal SF help and trailhead if you never used [early flows](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.flow_concepts_trigger_record.htm&type=5)

You'd make an one-off data fix to populate existing records and job done, normal field should be selectable as sharing rule criteria.

=====

But I smell trouble with your formula. What exactly you have there, something like `Experience__c = (TODAY() - DateofJoining__c) / 365`? That's bit evil. Formulas with TODAY(), NOW() or anything with $ (roughly speaking who's looking at the data, user's name, profile role... not what's actually on the record itself) are "nondeterministic". Unpredictable.

A "today()" changes just like that, without updating the record. Sure, when you watch the record a fresh value will be calculated but other than that LastModifiedDate doesn't change, there's no magical trigger running at midnight that rechecks sharing. (especially that there's no single midnight, you could have users in multiple timezones). SF just doesn't allow nondeterministic fields in many places, see https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/32122/799

So if you do rely on TODAY() in your formula you might have to make a "scheduled flow" or read about schedulable, batchable apex. Create nightly job that would run and recalculate your helper field with right experience. You'd probably even need both solutions, a "before save" flow for new data created today and nightly job to advance the clock on existing old data...